# Extract one row per customer and per year, pulled by minimum date available from all records- SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, greatest-n-per-group

I need to extract an entire row of data per customer (without aggregations) for each minimum date in the month of march per year. If there are three records of different dates in March 2023, I'll have to pull the row for the earliest of these three dates.

The below is the sample data, the are other fields I will be selecting too in my actual query and have simplified it.

| Date | Customer | Country. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3/22/2023 | Brooks Kihn | JM |
| 3/20/2023 | Brooks Kihn | JM |
| 3/1/2022 | Brooks Kihn | JM |
| 8/8/2021 | Brooks Kihn | JM |
| 3/5/2022 | Brooks Kihn | JM |
| 3/1/2021 | Brooks Kihn | JM |
| 3/8/2021 | Brooks Kihn | JM |
| 3/22/2023 | Monique Shanahan | CO |
| 3/20/2023 | Monique Shanahan | CO |
| 8/20/2023 | Monique Shanahan | CO |
| 3/1/2022 | Monique Shanahan | CO |
| 3/5/2022 | Monique Shanahan | CO |
| 3/1/2021 | Monique Shanahan | CO |
| 3/8/2021 | Monique Shanahan | CO |

The below is the result I am expecting, where there is one record from March, with the earliest data available within that month, and this repeating for each year 2021, 2022, 2023.

| Date | Customer | Country. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3/20/2023 | Brooks Kihn | JM |
| 3/1/2022 | Brooks Kihn | JM |
| 3/1/2021 | Brooks Kihn | JM |
| 3/20/2023 | Monique Shanahan | CO |
| 3/1/2022 | Monique Shanahan | CO |
| 3/1/2021 | Monique Shanahan | CO |

Thank you in advance for helping resolve this!

Comment: use row_number with customer and year as partiotion and order by date

Comment: Postgres != Redshift. Please tag only the one database you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter the table for any date in March, then use window functions to retain the top row per customer and year.

In Redshift:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*,
        rank() over(
            partition by customer, extract(year from date)
            order by date
        ) rn
    from mytable t
    where extract(month from date) = 3
) t
where rn = 1
order by customer, date
```

In Postgres, we could also use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (customer, extract(year from date)) t.*
from mytable t
where extract(month from date) = 3
order by customer, extract(year from date), date
```